# Add button after script tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript that I want my users to be able to put on their sites. In this javascript, I want to generate a simple button, that is located exactly where the javascript has been pasted into the site. How can I do this? It would be simple if I could give my `<script>` tag an id and then just getting the element with the specific ID and appending after it, but I can't.

For example if I have something like this:

```
<body>
<p>test para</p>
<p>test para</p><p>test para</p><p>test para</p>
<p>test para</p>
<div>test div</div>
<script src="embed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div>last div</div>
</body>
```

I want my button to be placed right between `test div` and `last div` (before or after the `script` tag, it doesn't matter). Can I do this?

Comment: is an iframe out of the question ? or a `data-` attribute? or a role attribute ?

Comment: iframe definitely yes. other than that, everything that works in major browsers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you just use `after` -

```
$("div:contains('test div')").after('<input type="button"/>');
```

This would obviously be better if you could give the 'div' an id or a class rather than finding it by the text it contains.

jQuery can find a script tag using -

```
$("script[src='embed.js']").after('<input type="button"/>')
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/7GPx7/1

Comment: That was only an example, I want to get the `script` element, not the `div` before it, cause maybe on one site it won't be a `div` before my script element, maybe it will be a `p` or something else.

Answer (score 2):

embedding JavaScript something you may want to consider is your visitors may not have jQuery enabled on their sites, so you could bloat the call by loading jQuery or construct your requirement in pure JavaScript.

The embed snippet for your visitors

```
<script id="eduard_luca" src="http://cdn.example.com/embed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

embed.js

```
var element = document.createElement('a');
element.setAttribute('href','http://google.com');
element.innerHTML = 'Click Me';

document.getElementById("eduard_luca").appendChild(element);
```

I Hope this help you with your project.

Comment: I'm handling the jQuery loading in my embed.js script (if not already loaded). So I guess giving a `script` tag an `id` is OK after all. Thanks.